# Find the interval of concavity of $x^{1/3}(x+4)$

Tags: calculus

Find the interval of concavity of $f(x)=x^{1/3}(x+4)$.

I am preparing  some practice problems and I found this.
Using the second derivative, 
The 'points of concern' are $x=0,x=2$. So partitioning the real line with these points gives $(-\infty, 0), (0,2), (2,\infty)$ 
but since the
 second derivative $f=\frac{4x-8}{9x^{5/3}}$ has no real solution on 
$(-\infty,0)$. I was thinking to discard this interval but  my calculus book (James Stewart, Biocalculus) says it is concave up on 
$(-\infty,0)$.

I am doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

$$f''(x)=\frac{4(x-2)}{9x^{\frac{5}{3}}}<0$$ for $0<x<2$ and since $f$ is a continuous function on the domain (which is $(0,+\infty)$), we get that $f$ is a concave function on $(0,2]$.

If you'll take $f(x)=\sqrt[3]{x}(x+4)$ then the domain is $\mathbb R$ and since
$$f''(x)=\frac{4(x-2)}{9\sqrt[3]{x^5}},$$
we obtain that $f$ is a concave function on $[0,2]$

and $f$ is a convex function on $(-\infty,0]$ and on $[2,+\infty)$.

Comment: Thank you, I think this part is clear. the little worry I have is with the interval $(-\infty,0)$ which is outside of the domain in the first place. The conclusion that it is concave up on this interval seem a bit confusing

Comment: @J. Kyei If we wrote $x^{\frac{1}{3}}$ then it's better to think that the domain of this expression is $(0,+\infty)$.

Comment: If I understand well, you mean there is a difference between the domain of $x^{1/3}(x+4)$ and  that of $\sqrt[3]{x}(x+4)$ ?

Comment: @J. Kyei Yes of course!